# VS code cursor not showing in the template of Vue project

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3

All of a sudden, I am facing this problem in my VS Code editor. If you look at the first picture, that is a code snipped of my VUE 3 project. Where ever I am clicking in the picture, the cursor is not appearing.
[image]

This is the same file with the other section, where the cursor seems to be fine. Its works smoothly...

Does anyone have any idea about this issue??
I also checked in Stack Overflow, some issues suggested reinstalling the VIM extension, whereas I don't have VIM installed in my docker environment.

[image]

Comment: why do the indent/tab guides not show in the top of the file

Comment: do you have the same behavior when using the VSC Insiders